# I'm trying to install Material Top Tabs Navigator React Native version 6.xx but getting errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React Native and I'm getting below errors after running this command npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: AppName@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@5.9.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^5.9.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/material-top-tabs@6.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/material-top-tabs
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/material-top-tabs@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-08T06_50_05_697Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force installation in this way:

```
npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view --force
```

Comment: @Manishkumar no problem, happy to help you. If you think the answer is correct, please, don't forget to mark it as valid. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by lowering the `npm 6.x.x` version.

```
brew install nvm // If there's no nvm
mkdir ~/.nvm
vi ~/.bash_profile // If you use zsh open ~/.zshrc
source ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc
nvm install 6
nvm use 6.x.x
```

- .zshrc or .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm 
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this  :

1. `yarn add @react-navigation/material-top-tabs`
2. `yarn add react-native-tab-view`